# Permutations of $n$ objects taken $r$ at a time with repetition allowed and a certain number of items are repeated.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Is there any formula for number of distinct permutations of a set with $N$ objects taken $r$ at a time with repetitions allowed, where objects $a_1,a_2,...a_i$ are repeated $k_1,k_2,...k_i$ times.

We know that if we have $N$ distinct objects taken $r$ at a time with repetitions allowed we have $N^r$ permutations. And if in a set where objects $a_1,a_2,...a_i$ are repeated $k_1,k_2,...k_i$ times, we have $\frac{N!}{k_1!k_2!...k_i!}$ permutations.

So I had thought it could be $\frac{N^r}{k_1!k_2!...k_i!}$ permutations if both situations were applicable. But a simple test of finding permutations of two objects taken a time with repetitions allowed in the set $(1,1,2,2,3,3,3)$ revealed it to be false as  $\frac{7^2}{2!2!3!}$ is a fraction.